# Prism for Xamarin Forms - Navigating from a tabbedpage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

(Using Prism 6.1.0-pre6 and XF 2.3.0.107)

**Summary**: Navigating to a ContentPage from a TabbedPage doesn't show the toolbar/actionbar.

I navigate to a TabbedPage (MainPage.xaml) from another page.  This looks like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Or.Console.Views"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Or.Console.Views.MainPage">
  <local:APage/>
  <local:BPage/>
  <local:CPage/>
</TabbedPage>
```

And in the ViewModel for APage, I'm calling

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("DetailsPage");
```

The DetailsPage is just a ContentPage, and I would expect that it would show with the back button and action bar at the top, but it doesn't.

I'm guessing this is because Prism doesn't know about the tab child pages, only the TabbedPage itself.

I've tried registering the tab child pages with Prism, but this doesn't seem to work.  Also tried wrapping each tab child in a NavigationPage, but this brings on some strange behavior with duplicate toolbars.

What's the right way to navigate from within tabbed content?

**EDIT**:
In response to Brian Lagunas answer, I tried wrapping the TabbedPage in a NavigationPage, so when I navigate to it, I'm calling

```
 _navigationService.NavigateAsync("DeviceNavWrapper/MainPage");
```

But this gives an odd result:
[image]

**EDIT2**: Solution in my case ended up that I needed to call NavigateAsync from APage with the useModalNavigation set to false. So now APage has this:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("DetailsPage", null, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Erin, this solves my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to get a back button at the top is to have the page nested inside a NavigationPage.  This is standard Xamarin.Forms behavior.  So you have a couple of options.  One would be to wrap your APage in a NavigationPage.  Then when you call NavigateAsync("DetailsPage") from APageViewModel, it will work as you want.

EDIT: If you want to navigate to a completely different Page and replace the TabbedPage, then make sure the TabbedPaged is wrapped in a NavigationPage, and navigate from the TabbedPageViewModel.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your response (and for the great work you've done on Prism XF).  Yes, that's exactly what I want - to replace the TabbedPage.  The problem I'm having is that wrapping the TabbedPage (MainPage) in a NavigationPage makes it display with a double toolbar.  I get the hamburger and the back button below it, and duplicate sets of action buttons.  Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: I guess my TabbedPage must already be wrapped in a navpage earlier in the stack, so hence the duplicate.  I ended up hacking a navigate call to the TabbedPage from the control in APage, and it worked! Now I have to figure out how to bind a command from the control on APage to the parent tabbedpage.  This seems do-able but less than desirable.. wonder if we might see an enhancement from Prism or XF to make this cleaner?

Comment: I can definitely see where this would be useful.  Right now only the modal navigation was considered.  For example, if you navigate modally from APage it would work (replace the tabbedPage), but haven't really considered navigating within a NaviagionPage. This might be a little tricky, but let me think about it.

Comment: Ah!  THAT is exactly what I needed.  If I just Navigate with the useModalNavigation flag set to false, I'll get the back button and the behavior I need.  I hadn't ever looked for it until you mentioned it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate duplicate Toolbar, I found out that settting

```
   NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

of the NavigationPage Wrapper easier